# How to display item in .aspx page using if

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here i want to display list menu element only based on if condition.
here i want to to check if `Session["user_id"] is empty or not`. if it is `empty` then display

```
        <li><a href="register.aspx">Register</a></li>           
        <li><a href="login.aspx">Login</a></li>
```

else display

```
<li><a href="login.aspx">Login</a></li>
```

index.aspx

```
<div class="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.aspx">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.aspx">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="feedback.aspx">Feedback</a></li>
            <li><a href="rti.aspx">RTI</a></li>
            <li><a href="faq.aspx">FAQ</a></li>
            <li><a href="contactus.aspx">Contact us</a></li>
            <li><a href="register.aspx">Register</a></li>           
            <li><a href="login.aspx">Login</a></li>         
        </ul>
    </div>
```

c#

```
String userID = Convert.ToString(Session["user_id"]);        
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userID) == true)
        {            
            Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
        }
```

how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.Net, you can mix html and C# :

```
    <% String userID = Convert.ToString(Session["user_id"]);        
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userID) == true)
    {  %>          
          <li><a href="register.aspx">Register</a></li>           
          <li><a href="login.aspx">Login</a></li> 
    <%}else{ %>
        <li><a href="login.aspx">Login</a></li>
    <%} %>
```